# cannot register delegate and data source of UITableView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

it says

> Assigning to 'id _Nullable' from incompatible
> type 'ChildTableViewCell *__strong'

is there any mistake if i implement UITableView cell inside custom UITableViewCell ?

1. So first in `MainViewController`, Using `MainView` that have `UITableView`,
2. in the `MainViewController`, especially in `ViewDidLoad`, i register `self.mainView.tableView.delegate = self;` also `self.mainView.dataSource = self;`
3. and in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` i have this:

> ```
> - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
> cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
>
> if ([self.filteredCategoriesAllListLocalDataArray count] > 0) {
>     static NSString *cellID = @"ChildTableViewCell";
>     
>     ChildTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
>     
>     if(nil == cell) {
>         cell = [[ChildTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
>                                                reuseIdentifier:cellID];
>         [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
>     }
>     
>     CategoryModel *currentCategory = [self.filteredCategoriesAllListLocalDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
>     ChildModel *currentChildData = [currentCategory.childModelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
>     NSLog(@"================== %@", currentChildData.nameString);
>     cell.childData = currentChildData;
>     [cell initializeChildTableView];
>     
>     cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
>     return cell;
> }
>
>    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
>    return cell; 
> }
> ```

4. and then in ChildTableViewCell i have this:

> ```
> - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
> self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
>
> if (self) {
>     _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen
> mainScreen].bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.contentView.frame))style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
>     self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
>     self.tableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
>     self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
>     self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
>     self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
>     self.tableView.delegate = self;
>     self.tableView.dataSource = self;
>     [self.contentView addSubview:self.tableView];
> }
>     
>    return self;
> }
> ```

but in step 4, got this error message:

> Assigning to 'id _Nullable' from incompatible
> type 'ChildTableViewCell *__strong'

im Using UITableView inside UItableViewCell cause want to make UITAbleView Tree Level with custom data, i've been search all reference for UITableView Multi level but it doesn't help at all.

Comment: Why are you trying to assign delegate and data source for a table view inside it's own cell? A delegate and data source is usually assigned outside the tableview. You are likely creating a loop where the data source / delegate needs to be defined before the table can render and your table won't render because you want to define the data source / delegate inside the cell

Comment: Also, please share your code to get a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so other's can help debug it and solve your error.

Comment: hi @ParthTamane here it is, i already update my question

Comment: Did you add conformance to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableviewDataSource` to your cell subclass?  By the way, nested tableview are not typically a great solution. Can you use a single tableview with multiple sections?

Comment: Yes @Paulw11, i register delegates inside cell. I tried using single tableview and multiple selection for level 1 im good at it.  But how to make multilevel till level 3 ? Like this https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSAwqIqcSOJ_k8L8fiy5VXSxKgjMmckVocvQA&usqp=CAU , i already research about a week, to solve my issue but no hint at allz

Comment: @Paulw11 And this is my related problem why im using nested tableview, please take a look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67294438/from-json-with-model-to-uitableview-multilevel

Comment: The error message indicates that your cell subclass doesn't conform to the required protocols/interfaces.